# cakephp does not save cookie

Tags: cakephp, cookies

I have this simple code in my AppController beforeFilter function, to set a cookie

```
$this->Cookie->name = 'MyCookie';
$this->Cookie->time =  '1 hour';
$this->Cookie->domain = 'example.com';

$myCookie = $this->Cookie->read('my_cookie');

if ( empty($myCookie) ) {
    $this->Cookie->write('my_cookie', 'cookieValue', true);
} else {
    echo $myCookie;die;
}
```

So, as I refresh the page for the second time it should echo the cookie's value. But it does not. The output is nothing. Any ideas what can be the problem ?

I use cake 2.3.1. Cookie component is included. Debug level is 3 and there are no errors. I have checked the cake logs file - nothing there.

Thanks

Comment: Assuming that your code actually works, then, maybe your server's date/time isn't quite right VS the computer your browser runs on?  You should investigate the HTTP headers being sent to the browser using developer tools. In Chrome, you can hit CTRL+SHIFT+C, then check out the "network" tab (and then refresh).

Comment: Thanks @starlocke for the comment, the time is the same as computer's time, I can see the cookie's variable in request and response headers under the network tab `MyCookie[my_cookie]=Q2FrZQ%3D%3D.4oyrGqYlDHw1hCc%3D`, but in fact it is not being set